# Having trouble passing Redux state to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux, and I've been working with the code for [the very first example project in the Redux docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter/src). That example doesn't use containers or have separate files for actions, so I figured I'd start there and try to abstract it a bit.

The project doesn't have an `App` component, and the **index.js** file looks like this to start:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import Counter from './components/Counter'
import counter from './reducers'

const store = createStore(counter)
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter
    value={store.getState()}
    onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}
    onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}
  />,
  rootEl
)

render()
store.subscribe(render)
```

I first changed this so that it mounted an `App` component instead:

```
...

import { Provider } from 'react-redux':

...

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've moved the `Counter` component into **App.js**, and I tried to use `mapStateToProps` to bring in the initial state (set to `state = 0` in the reducer):

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from '../components/Counter.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Counter value={value} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { value: state.value };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I'm trying to pass the `Counter` the `value` prop that is set in `mapStateToProps`.

With the code above, I get the error at `<Counter value={value} />`:

> **'value' is not defined  no-undef**

As crazy as it sounds, I thought maybe I had to initialize `value` inside a `constructor` function for `App` in order to make this work:

```
constructor() {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: 0
    }
}
```

This didn't work, and it doesn't make sense anyway given that state is initialized in the reducer.

Comment: rpivovar Please let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple you are doing it right but you just need to change a little in your render method just to get the updated value your problem will be solved.

Just make these changes in your App component you there you go.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Counter from '../components/Counter.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      props: {
        value
      }
    } = this;
    return(
        <div>
            <Counter value={value} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You don't need to `initialize` value in the `constructor` method.

Answer (score 1):

The value which is returned from mapStateToProps becomes part of the props. So, 'value' will be part of the props. You can access 'value' by:

```
<Counter value={this.props.value} />
```